# Какой выбрать сетевой накопитель для офиса

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

У заказчика встал вопрос покупки сетевого накопителя для офиса. Нужно поднять на нем VM, чтобы сотрудники подключались через удаленный рабочий стол к серверу и могли работать там с файлами. Не устраивает вариант скачивания и выгрузки файлов через FTP или веб-интерфейс, нужно прям напрямую с ними работать.
Что посоветуете, надо покупать сервер или сетевой накопитель потянет? И какие мин характеристики у накопителя должны быть?

Answer (score 0):

Есть NAS - сетевое хранилище через Windows Home Server, говорят что мало чем отличается от обычного компьютера.  Но я бы рекомендовал связку сетевого хранилища и какого-то сервера с гипервизором (vmware, например). Или же один сервак с большим объемом памяти для жосткого диска/дисков. На виртуалке можно поднять, к примеру, самба сервер и будет общий доступ сотрудников к файлам.